# Restricting a People Picker to only select people from one Sharepoint group programatically

Tags: asp.net, people-picker

I've a got a People Picker on a custom list form, and I'm trying to restrict the people you can select in it. Basically, if the form is in one state (set in Page_Load), then restrict the people that can be selected to one Sharepoint group, if it is the second state, select from a different Sharepoint group.

Is this at all possible, or is any restriction of a People Picker something that needs to be set in the corresponding list field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PeopleEditor control exposes a property [SharePointGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.peopleeditor.sharepointgroup). This should give you a bit of what you want - it will mean the Browse window only shows members of that group.

However, I think I remember discovering that [you could still type other users](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sharepointdevelopment/thread/3e5e9a22-9c34-4856-808f-275518e8e6ba) (not in that group) in and that they'd still validate.

Comment: Ya. I have tried the SharePointgroup property. However, it will also valid if I enter user name to the field directly.